# JPEG image not rendering completely or at all

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have to move an old script to a new server. The script generates a pdf file with a list of products with some related data and product image. After moving all files to new server and adapting to new environement this is what I've stumbled upon (this is how the images in generated pdf look like):

[image]
[image]

Some of the images are not completely rendered. Some of them are not rendered at all. There is no error whatsoever. Path and files exists, permissions are in order. All files are **jpg**. Some of them I had to reduce considerably to have them appear but the quality is miserable.

Code:

```
$this->Image($file, $this->GetX(), $this->GetY(), $pz->img_info->width, $pz->img_info->height, '', $link_url, '', true, 150);
```

On the other hand on the old server there was no problem with generating a 30MB pdf, with various image sizes.

Had someone encountered similar problem? How did you resolve it?

The new config is **php 7.3.33**, **GD 2.3.3**, **TCPDF 6.5.0**, **ORACLELinux**

Script settings:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
set_time_limit(600);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('gd.jpeg_ignore_warning', 0);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

PHP ini settings:

```
max_execution_time  30
memory_limit    128M
```

Comment: Edited question with script settings

Comment: Edited with php ini settings, thing is, the pdf file is generated and its ok, the only thing is the images are broken

Comment: ok. now please tell us whether the whole PHP execution will last more than 30 seconds ?

Comment: yes if there is a lot of images. never counted the total time but it was easly exceeding 30s hence the additional time limit. The old server was a Fedora from 2010 with a lot less of resources and php 5.2, and sometimes it was processing more than a minute without any problems.

Comment: Please note that ini_set may not be effective in certain servers, please edit the php.ini file, restart the httpd and re-try.

Comment: Changed the .ini as you indicated but no luck :/

Comment: Yes, now max_execution_time  600 and memory_limit    512M

Comment: You also mentioned : **image upload not working today: Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server** , what error is it ? (tell us the error message pls) . BTW, so each time you generate the PDF you will need to go thru the file upload step ?

Comment: image upload not working today: Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server -> I cannot upload an image as example to the question, some error on stackoverflow prevents it

Comment: all images are already on the server, there is no uploading involved. Only reading from predefined folder.

Comment: will it be possible that the images whuch appear broken are really corrupted ? it is because you are moving (hence uploading) files to the new servers and if there are problems/errors during the transfer it can happen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248792/discussion-between-user1398498-and-ken-lee).